# I need help to understand CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Tags: c++, c, clock

I use `AMD FX 4300` with `3.8GHz`, that means `3.8G` clocks per sec.
But when I run the command `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` it shows something else.

```
#include <time.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main()    
{       
   printf("%lu\n",CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   return 0;
}
```

it shows: `1000`

Is it right?

Is there any problem in my processor or the working of this program?

Comment: These days I would just use `std::chrono`

Comment: ***Is there any problem in my processor or the working of this program?*** I say neither. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not measuring cpu cycles. Although even if it was that is not so good today being that your cpu will dynamically adjust the multiplier anyways..

Comment: 'it shows: `1000`' - it's all your fault. Stop running a non-POSIX compliant system and you'll see the performance [boosted by 1000](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) :D

Comment: `CLOCK_PER_SEC` is just a system clock, not an hardware one.

Answer (score 1):

Putting other issues aside, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` isn't dependable.

for example ([see the linux `clock` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock)):

> POSIX requires that CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 independent of the actual resolution.

Comment: That doesn't mean it isn't dependable, you can depend on it to be `1000000`, just as POSIX defines it, every time you call it. The issue I think you are hinting at is there will be little correlation between what you are using `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` for and your processor ticks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   that's mostly true  however, not everyone implements the POSIX requirement. So I guess both are true, since on most systems (but not all) you can depend on the POSIX value.

Comment: There was a small wink and nod buried in the comment above `:)`